# How to find out which JDK (not JRE) an installation of Eclipse on Windows is using

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

How can I find out where the JDK which Eclipse is using to compile resides? It's possible to find the location(s) of JREs in Window, Preferences, Java. Even the compiler level (1.7) is there.

I can also find out which version of Java is installed using "where java", but "where javac" does not yield a result.

Since .java files can be compiled, some Java compiler (so a JDK) must be present. It's very tedious to search all directories and hasn't shown a usable result yet.

Somewhere in Eclipse's settings the path to the JDK must be saved. As far as I know, JAVA_HOME environment variable isn't used.

So how can I find out where the used JDK is? I actually need to find the programs xjc and schemagen, but the search of the total disk couldn't find it. I find this contradictory.

Comment: window -> preferences -> java -> installed JRE

Comment: eclipse has its own compiler so 'compilability' as a test of JDK presence fails (and eclipse can work off a JRE http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation)

Answer (score 1):

Help menu -> About -> Installation details button -> Configuration tab

Here you can find all system properties and Eclipse arguments including:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaw.exe
```

This is the Java VM on which Eclipse runs.

Eclipse has its internal compiler. It does not use `javac` to compile Java sources, Eclipse doesn't even require JDK just a JRE (and is still able to compile Java sources).

Comment: That surprises me. But even if Eclipse can compile Java sources, it needs some kind of java compiler. It may have its own, but it has to be somewhere. And how can I tell to which Java standard it adheres? Although I have Oracle's JDK 8 installed, Eclipse only offers me 1.7 as the highest compiler level. Is this related to the Java compiler included in Eclipse (which is Kepler, not Luna)? Can I tell Eclipse to use the installed JDK 8 instead of its own compiler?

Comment: As said, Eclipse has its internal compiler. And yes it is somewhere, inside the Eclipse folder (plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.* for example). [More on the built in compiler.](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) And Kepler's compiler only supports 1.7, Luna's compiler also supports Java 1.8. You can tell Eclipse to use `javac` but then you lose features like errors while you're typing, it will be slow etc. Eclipse's built-in compiler is incremental. To specify a new compiler: Right click on project -> Preferences -> Builders. Here you can add javac for exmaple or an ant script.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs The Eclipse community has released a Java8 patch for it's kepler version

Answer (score 0):

**window -> preferences -> java -> installed JREs** -> if there are more jre then select the right one and check the location for JDK or JRE installation directory